# How can you compile VST 3 or Audio Units with the command line?

Tags: cmake, audiounit, vst

I would like to make an audio plugin, as either an Audio Unit or a VST 3. However, compiling plugins under both frameworks seems to be a very heavyweight process for which only XCode or Visual Studio project files are provided as examples. Is there an example of a barebones build that compiles using a Makefile or CMake script?

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the flags that Xcode uses and provide them to gcc with CMake. However, the actual build process generally takes much more time than the build tool and dependency analyzer itself. C++ compilers in particular are known to be quite slow.