# How do you compile a VST Plugin?

Tags: audio, compilation, vst

I've been working on an Audio Unit Plugin. Since I'd like people on Windows to be able to use the plugin, I've decided to try my hand at the VST3 SDK. I do not want to use JUCE because I may end up selling the product and don't want to live in a cardboard box afterwards (JUCE commercial licenses are rather pricey). I've hit the following problem with little luck finding an answer online: How do you compile a VST plugin for use in a host on Windows? I have the VST SDK and ASIO and VSTModuleArchitecture downloaded from the Steinberg website. I guess it's probably an elementary question, but I've really hit a brick wall on how to compile.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996027/how-can-you-compile-vst-3-or-audio-units-with-the-command-line) because my question is specific to Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to compile AGain.  Go to:

`{SDK Folder}\public.sdk\samples\vst2.x\again\win`

Assuming you have Visual Studio, double-click on "again.vcproj".  It'll create a project "again.vcxproj", which you can then build normally.

FWIW: I don't see you likely living in a cardboard box using JUCE.  I too think it's too pricey for comfort, and isn't entirely essential; but it costs nothing to develop in, and your license for your first plugin costs substantially less.  The license for the second and further plugins is full price.  It's not a subscription, but a lifetime license.  Once it's bought, you never have to pay more.  By contrast, while you have to sign a confidentiality agreement and I can't be sure, rumor has it that developing an AAX plugin for ProTools costs $500/year, which you start paying BEFORE you start developing, and then have to continue paying to continue to sell.  Don't sell enough to make it worth $500/year?  Tough cookies.  After 10 years, it costs HUGELY more than JUCE.  Developing for AAX is MUCH more likely to lead to a cardboard box than JUCE.